# pandas: series values at array of index values

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a `pandas` `Series` instance defined as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
timestamps = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
quantities = [1,9,6,6,6,4,4,4,5,2]
series = pd.Series(quantities, index=timestamps)
```

Is it possible to supply an array of index values and retrieve the quantities at them? And if it is, what's the fastest way of achieving this, please?

For example, if I supply:

```
timestamps = [1,1,1,4]
```

I expect the following back from `series`:

```
quantities = [1,1,1,6]
```

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible:

```
>>> series[[1,1,1,4]]
1    1
1    1
1    1
4    6
dtype: int64
>>> series[[1,1,1,4]].values
array([1, 1, 1, 6])
```